# Application of squeeze theorem in $\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

The problem goes as follows: Let $F:$ $\mathbb{R^2}$ \ $\{(-1,1)\}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R^2}$ the function defined by

$$F(x,y) = (g(x,y), h(x,y))$$

Prove using the **squeeze theorem** that:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (-1,1)} F(x,y) = (a,b) \iff \lim_{(x,y) \to (-1,1)} g(x,y) = a \text{ and } \lim_{(x,y) \to (-1,1)} h(x,y) = b.$$

I think this statement can be proved very straightfoward by definition ($\epsilon -  \delta$), however, the original statement asks to prove this using squeeze theorem, and here is where I don't know how to start. It is possible to do so with the squeeze theorem? If so, any hints are appreciated. If it is not possible, I would like to know if is possible to prove by $\epsilon -  \delta$ just as I think.

Comment: I agree - the epsilon-delta proof is straightforward, and it's unclear how the squeeze theorem would be applied (especially for the "$\impliedby$" direction, since the "$\le$" in the hypotheses of the squeeze theorem is not even defined on $\Bbb R^2$). I'm curious what the problem writer had in mind.

Comment: I don't understand how you could squeeze without $\leq$

Comment: We need more context.